# React Redux MapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Why do I get `undefined` returned when I access the state? I use the Redux DevTools and see the state correctly updated via an action but I just cannot access the state values for some reason. I get this sort of object returned when I access `state.dog` which seems wrong:

```
ct {size: 1, _root: pt, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
```

Here is my container code:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Message from '../../components/message';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.dog.hasBarked);
    return {
        message: state.dog.hasBarked ? 'Barked' : 'It is quiet',
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Message);
```

Here is the dog reducer:

```
import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
import { MAKE_BARK } from '../actions/dog';

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
    hasBarked: false,
});

const dogReducer = (state: Object = initialState, action: Object) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case MAKE_BARK:
        return state.set('hasBarked', action.payload);
    default:
        return state;
    }
};

export default dogReducer;
```

Comment: once show your `dog reducer`

Comment: Please add your reducer's code to the question to help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using immutable. state.dog is not a simple js array but a immutable map or list. You can access it natively with state.dog.toObject().hasBarked.

Comment: Thanks, Immutable was being used.